# Next js: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm using `next js` and I want to import rich text editor in my project, but when I tried to import `react-draft-wysiwyg` then show me error like this:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3736:30
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3739:9)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3395:29)
    at renderToString (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3954:27)
    at render (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\node_modules\next-server\dist\server\render.js:79:16)
    at renderPage (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\node_modules\next-server\dist\server\render.js:255:20)
    at C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\.next\server\static\development\pages\_document.js:437:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\.next\server\static\development\pages\_document.js:206:24)
    at _next (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\.next\server\static\development\pages\_document.js:228:9)
    at C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\.next\server\static\development\pages\_document.js:235:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\_export.js:36:28)
    at C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\.next\server\static\development\pages\_document.js:224:12
    at Function.getInitialProps (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\.next\server\static\development\pages\_document.js:445:7)
    at Object.loadGetInitialProps (C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\seo blog\frontend\node_modules\next-server\dist\lib\utils.js:50:35)
```

but same editor if I import in `create-react-app` then it works fine, I don't know why not working in my `next js` project.

I have tried code in my `next js` like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from "draft-js";
//import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const { Editor } = dynamic(() => import("react-draft-wysiwyg"), { ssr: false });
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";
import "../../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
// import htmlToDraft from "html-to-draftjs";

const BlogCreate = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
  });

  const onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  const { editorState } = state;
  return (
    <div>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
        editorClassName="demo-editor"
        onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
        placeholder="write something..."
      />
      <textarea
        disabled
        value={draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogCreate;
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: that error stack would have pointed you to a line, which is the line that gives you the error?

Comment: Now I have add my full error message, actually I have no idea where is error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't destructure next/dynamic

change this line

```
const { Editor } = dynamic(() => import("react-draft-wysiwyg"), { ssr: false });
```

by

```
const Editor = dynamic(() => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then(mod => mod.Editor), { ssr: false });
```

Comment: It runs but is giving TS error. Argument of type '() => Promise<React.ComponentClass<never, any> | React.FunctionComponent<never> | { default: React.ComponentType<never>; } | typeof Editor>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'.